# What is the problem with D3js working with Internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, d3.js, internet-explorer-11, donut-chart

I am creating an SVG donut chart using D3js v4 library, and it works fine with Google chrome but it doesn't work at all with IE11

I tried to to put the code in this Codepen
'https://codepen.io/ohmto/pen/eYZeYqW'

any help or a reason why it doesn't work on IE11, it will be appreciated

Comment: Your code has arrow functions, you cannot use them on IE: https://caniuse.com/arrow-functions

Answer (score 0):

I try to check your code and found => arrow functions in it. [Arrow functions](https://caniuse.com/arrow-functions) are not supported in the IE browser.

I try to modify your sample code and try to convert the arrow functions to normal functions to make it work with the IE browser.

After modifying the code, I noticed that the chart getting created but it is not in the proper format and data are missing too.

output in the IE 11 browser:

[image]

I again try to modify the JS and CSS code but the result was the same.

Further, I try to check the [D3.JS](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki#supported-environments) and [SVG](https://caniuse.com/svg) related documents.

You can notice that SVG has partial support in the IE browser.

Some parts of D3.js may also not work with the older browsers.

[image]

You can try to simplify your sample and check whether it works with the IE. If it does not work then I suggest you use the JS code to identify the browser and inform users to visit the site using compatible browsers for your site.